# adding numbered column to csv file

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have a csv file that looks like this. 
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSxv.png)

I would like to in python open this file and change the values of all the 0s in the first column to 1, 2, 3, 4 .... to the last number of the last row in the file. 
if you could let me know how to do that I would greatly appreciate it. 
atm I am writing data to the file by doing this.

```
def save_train_data_7_days(filename, df1):

FIELDNAMES = [
    'id',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    'host',
    'type'
    ]

if not os.path.exists(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
        writer.writeheader()

else:
    with open(filename, 'a') as fp:
        df1.to_csv(fp, header=False)

def format_train_data(filename, df1):
    with open(filename, )



for i, j in enumerate(range(1, 230)):
    df1 = df.iloc[:,i+1:i+8]
    print(df1)

    save_train_data_7_days("training_data.csv", df1)
```

Comment: Please include the sample data in the question in code tags. Never use images of source, json, CSV etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df['id']=df.index
df.to_csv(filepath)
```

If the ID column does not appear in the desired position in the dataframe, you may have to reorder the columns in the dataframe before saving to csv.

Answer (score 0):

Using DictWriter/DictReader is a good idea!
You should do something like:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(fp_to_write)
reader = csv.DictReader(fp_to_read)
index = 0
for row in reader:
    row['id'] = index
    writer.write(row)
    index += 1
```